# Allow the user to control what happens

Tags: c#

I am using C# to create an application that communicates with an Arduino over serial. I have buttons that send certain letters over serial to tell the Arduino what to do. The Arduino will be controlling a RGB LED light strip. But I want the user to be able to add buttons and give what RGB values will be sent when the user presses the button. I have figured out how to add buttons and all but I want to know how to create a individual event handlers for each button that has been added.

```
int h = 5;
int l = 5;       
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point newLoc = new Point(h, l);
    List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
    Button newButton = new Button();
    newButton.Text = buttonNameTextBox.Text;
    newButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(253)))), ((int)(((byte)(199)))), ((int)(((byte)(13)))));
    newButton.Size = new Size(150, 50);
    newButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 15F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    newButton.Location = newLoc;
    newLoc.Offset(0, newButton.Height + 5);
    newButton.
    buttons.Add(newButton);
    newButton.Name = componentNameTextBox.Text;
    this.Controls.Add(newButton);
    l += 65;
    newButton.Click += new EventHandler(newButton_Click);
}
```

So this is what I have to create the buttons and place the buttons. What my ultimate goal is to be able to have the user input the RGB value they would like for the LEDs so that when the press the button it will send them.

Comment: You can attach one event handler to multiple controls and then use the `sender` parameter to determine which button was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the same event handler for all of them (ie `newButton_Click`), and use the `sender` parameter to determine which one was clicked, or use an inline lambda function that will have access to all the surrounding variables already:

```
int h = 5;
int l = 5;       
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point newLoc = new Point(h, l);
    List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
    Button newButton = new Button();
    newButton.Text = buttonNameTextBox.Text;
    newButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(253)))), ((int)(((byte)(199)))), ((int)(((byte)(13)))));
    newButton.Size = new Size(150, 50);
    newButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 15F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    newButton.Location = newLoc;
    newLoc.Offset(0, newButton.Height + 5);
    newButton.
    buttons.Add(newButton);
    newButton.Name = componentNameTextBox.Text;
    this.Controls.Add(newButton);
    l += 65;
    newButton.Click += (s, ea) => {
        //Here is an event handler just for this button.  You can access
        //the surrounding variables (such as l, or newButton.BackColor etc) right here.
    };
}
```

You say you want to allow users to pass in the values - on the assumption that you might have 3 textboxes to do so, it means that this function could look like this:

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  /* as before... */

  int red = Convert.ToInt32(txtRed.Text);
  int green = Convert.ToInt32(txtGreen.Text);
  int blue = Convert.ToInt32(txtBlue.Text);

  newButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);

  newButton.Click += (s, ea) => {
    //made up function call to show how you can use the rgb values inline here
    ArduinoController.SendRGB(red, green, blue);
  }
}
```